# Change A Character In A String Using Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex3

What is the opposite of `String.charAt()`??

If I Have a string:

`var Str:String="Hello World";`

How do I change the 5th character, for example, from a ' ' to an '_'?

I can GET the 5th character like this:

`var C:String=Str.charAt(5);`

But how do I SET the 5th character?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat. One, off the top of my head, would involve String.substr:

```
var Str:String="Hello World"
var newStr:String = Str.substr(0,5) + "_" + Str.substr(6);
```

or, the same as above, but more generalized:

```
function setCharAt(str:String, char:String,index:int):String {
    return str.substr(0,index) + char + str.substr(index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot set any characters. Strings in ECMAScript (including ActionScript) are immutable. One thing you can do is to construct a new string containing the desired characters, as proposed here.

However, if you plan to modify the string a lot, the best is to rather have an array of characters, that you can mutate at will. When you need to print it, you simply `join` it with `""` as separator.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 1):

That answer was such a big help, but i think theres an easyer way. Suppose you want to replace the 4th character of a string called B by the letter "w". You can use

```
B = B.replace(B.charAt(4), "w");
```

Im using flash cs4 with actionscript 3.0, if it doesnt works with someone, let me know. If theres a evenbetter way of doing it let me know aswell.

Comment: This solution is not preferable, because `replace()` will replace the first instance it finds of the character retrieved from `charAt(4)` and not necessarily the instance at index 4. If B == "bellborn", it would become "wellborn" rather than "bellworn".

Comment: The charAt() method returns the character at the specified index in a string.The index of the first character is 0, the second character is 1, and so on. Hence, code has to be `B = B.replace(B.charAt(3), "w");`

Answer (score 1):

```
//Replacing "/" with "-"
var str:String = "he/ll/o"
str = str.split("/").join("-"); //str = he-ll-o
```