# In Flex- special characters entered in TxtBox should be replaced with a blank space

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, textbox, keyboard-events, flex2

**Requirement:**
I want it to do dynamically. I do not want the user to see a special character entered into the textBox. Instead of the special character the user should see only a blank space entered in the place of the special character. Is it possible to do such event. I tried many ways but could not achieve it. Its is very challenging , someone please help me

MXML Code:

```
<mx:TextInput x="10" y="25" id="txtSearch" width="200" enter="btnSearch_Click();" keyDown="txtSearch_KeyUpHandler(event);"/>
```

AS Code:

```
private function txtSearch_KeyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if(!((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)||(event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90)||(event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 112)))
    {
        //event.preventDefault();
        event.charCode = 32;
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code, it did not execute as expected. The special characters are being entered in the txtSearch text box.
I am not sure about what has went wrong here. Can you please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: try `textInput="Myfun(event)"` event instead keyDown

Comment: I have tried even the following code : 
private function txtSearch_KeyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
 if(!((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)||(event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90)||(event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 112)))
    {
     var lastIndex:int = txtSearch.text.length-1;
     var Str:String = txtSearch.text.charAt(lastIndex);
     var Str2:String = Str.charAt(lastIndex);
     txtSearch.text = txtSearch.text.replace(Str2,"_");
     //event.preventDefault();
       //event.charCode = 32;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the above is

at the enter function loop the text entered, and

search for special character and [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831502/change-a-character-in-a-string-using-actionscript) with by space.

Its better to use the regular expression on the enter
click.