# AS3 - Intercept and replace input text

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there some way to intercept text when it is typed in a text field and replace it with something else before it appears?

I'm developing a Flash game for learning French and I want to allow users to type accents on a US keyboard. On the French keyboard, the 'é' is produced by the '2' key. Since the game doesn't need numbers, I would like users to be able to press '2' and have an 'é' appear in the text field (and similarly with the other accents).

I was hoping to be able to use a key_down event handler like this:

```
function myInputOnKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent) {
     if (event.keyCode == 50) {
         event.charCode = 233; // = the code for 'é'
     }
}
```

This has worked in other platforms, but doesn't seem to work at all in Actionscript 3. I've tried using key_down, key_up, text_input events, tweaking things a dozen different ways, but with no success: I don't seem to be able to change the event properties, just read them.

I also tried stopping event propagation and inserting the accented characters manually. This works fine in normal use (using `appendText()`, for example), but reproducing all the behavior of a text field would be too much coding: inserting at the cursor, not just at the end; replacing any selected text, and so on.

The best I've come up with so far is to add a replace function to a key_up handler along the lines of: `text.replace(/2/, 'é')`. The problem with this is that the user can see the number 2 for half a second before it is replaced by the accented character: in other words it looks amateurish. I would like the characters to just appear, as if they were using a French keyboard.

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Key down handler and event.stopImmediatePropagation() should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to change the text which appears in the input box. I still get a '2' instead of an 'é'.

Comment: ah sorry was very late for me when I posted this, you won't be able to modify the event you'll have to manually update the text in the input box, SO post on replacing a character in a string in AS3 here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831502/change-a-character-in-a-string-using-actionscript